# Comparing columns in two files and one column should be in the range between -3 to +3 giving union of two files using perl

Tags: perl

I would like to compare three columns in two files and third column can be in a range between -3 to +3 giving me union of two files. 
file 1

```
miR156a AT1G27360   1253
miR156a AT1G27370   2368
miR156a AT1G53160   586
```

file 2

```
miR156a AT1G27360   1252    
miR156a AT1G27370   2367    
miR156a AT1G53160   123 
miR156a AT1G69170   1296
```

Expected output would be

```
miR156a AT1G27360   1253
miR156a AT1G27370   2368
miR156a AT1G53160   586
miR156a AT1G53160   123 
miR156a AT1G69170   1296
```

I have tried writing a perl script in which i could find only the intersection but not able to get the union of two files

```
open(FH1, "$filename1");
open(FH2, "$filename2");
while ( $line1 = <FH1> ) {
    chomp $line1;
    @temp = split(/\s+/, $line1);
    if ($#temp > 1) {
        push(@miR_TP, $temp[0]);
        push(@tar_TP, $temp[1]); 
        push(@start_TP, $temp[2]); 
    }
}
while ( $line2 = <FH2> ) {
    chomp $line2;
    @temp2 = split(/\s+/, $line2);
    if($#temp > 1) {
        push(@miR, $temp2[0]);
        push(@tar, $temp2[1]); 
        push(@start, $temp2[2]);        
    }
}
for ($i=0 ; $i<=$#miR ; $i++) {
    for($j=0 ; $j<=$#miR_TP ; $j++) {
        if (    ($miR[$i] eq $miR_TP[$j]) && 
            ($tar[$i] eq $tar_TP[$j]) &&
            (
                ($start[$i] eq $start_TP[$j])    ||
                ($start[$i] eq  $start_TP[$j]+1) ||
                ($start[$i] eq  $start_TP[$j]+2) ||
                ($start[$i] eq  $start_TP[$j]+3) ||
                ($start[$i] eq  $start_TP[$j]-1) ||
                ($start[$i] eq  $start_TP[$j]-2) ||
                ($start[$i] eq  $start_TP[$j]-3)
            )) {
            print "$miR[$i]\t$tar[$i]\t$start[$i]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly help me in modifying the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of arrays, use a hash. Instead of the complicated condition, use the `abs` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $filename1 = 'file1';
my $filename2 = 'file2';

my %hash;

open my $FH, '<', $filename1 or die $!;

while (my $line = <$FH>)
{
    chomp $line;
    my ($mir, $tar, $start) = split ' ', $line;
    if (defined $start)
    {
        print $line, "\n";                   # Always show file 1.
        push @{ $hash{$mir}{$tar} }, $start;
    }
}

open $FH, '<', $filename2 or die $!;
while (my $line = <$FH>)
{
    chomp $line;
    my ($mir, $tar, $start) = split ' ', $line;
    unless (exists $hash{$mir}
            and exists $hash{$mir}{$tar}
            and grep 3 >= abs $start - $_, @{ $hash{$mir}{$tar} })
    {
              print $line, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u tell me if i need only intersection of the two files and i did not get the first while loop u have used in the code.

Comment: To get the intersection, remove the `print` from the first loop and change `unless` to `if`. The first loop goes through the input line by line and remembers all the data in a hash. I did not know whether multiple starts per mir and tar are possible, so the program stores an array of them.

Comment: I am sorry but i guess ur code has some bug, its giving me more lines than expected once. Kindly check and let me know

Comment: @TarakaRamji: Heh. Please provide the input I can test the code against.

Comment: The no of lines is nearly 500. How should i provide the data?

Comment: @TarakaRamji: Just provide the *relevant* data.

Comment: I am sorry...The code is correct. I have made some mistake.I seriously apologize for my comment...Thank u very much...it worked good.